# How to append the Pseudo-class (active) to <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm using pseudo classes to decorate my xxx. My question is, how to force one of them to be active in the very beginning.

I have two < div >...< /div > as followings:

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
```

And I've style them by following css code:

```
#A {
    background: url('/xxx/xxx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#A:hover {
    background: url('/xxx/xxx_hover.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#A:active {
    background: url('/xxx/xxx_active.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#B {
    background: url('/xxx/xxx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#B:hover {
    background: url('/xxx/xxx_hover.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#B:active {
    background: url('/xxx/xxx_active.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

I want to active B once the page is loaded, how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there's another ("more proper") way already. But this is how I generally do this:

```
#A.active,
#A:active {
    background: url('/xxx/xxx_active.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

<div id="A" class="active"></div>
```

This assumes you'd use scripting to remove the class, if necessary. Or, when another page is requested, the class is set on another element, in the back-end.